# Content Resolver throws Null Pointer Exception while inserting into DATA.CONTENT_URI

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, contactscontract

I am using below code to add custom Mimetype in Android Contacts . This code is throwing an error on the below line

**getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);**

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference**

```
public static final String MIMETYPE_FORMALITY = "vnd.android.cursor.item/ABCAPPLICATION";
    public MainActivity saveFormality() {

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, this.getFormality() ? "1" : "0");
            int mod = getContentResolver().update(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    values,
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + "2231" + " AND "
                            + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= '"
                            + MIMETYPE_FORMALITY + "'", null);

            if (mod == 0) {
                values.put(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID, Long.valueOf("2231"));
                values.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, MIMETYPE_FORMALITY);
                **getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);** // This line was throwing null pointer exception. 

                Log.v("mimeType", "Inserted");
            }
        return this;
    }
```

I have copied this code from Stackoverflow post But it is not working. Can someone explain me the reason why it is throwing this error.

Comment: `public MainActivity saveFormality() ` ?? A public function that returns an activity instance? Or what is it? What happens? In which class are you using this?

Comment: `copied this code from Stackoverflow post`. You should post a link of course. Maybe you use the code wrong. We wanna check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have guarantee that this will solve your issue because you haven't posted your full stack trace, but in general, you can't insert rows into `Data.CONTENT_URI` by `CONTACT_ID`, the `ContactsContract` DB works like this:

1. `Contacts` - each entry represents one contact, and groups together one or more `RawContacts`
2. `RawContacts` - each entry represents data about a contact that was synced in by some `SyncAdapter` (e.g. Whatsapp, Google, Facebook, Viber), this groups multiple Data entries
3. `Data` - The actual data about a contact, emails, phones, etc. each line is a single piece of data that belongs to a single `RawContact`

So when adding a Data row, you must specify the exact RawContact._ID it'll go into, via `Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID = ...`, no need to specify the `CONTACT_ID` since the `RawContact` already belongs to some `Contact`

This is the same way to do updates to existing data as well.

As a side note:

- When reporting crashes, always post your full stack trace
- Reduce your code to the minimum code displaying the crash, so other stuff like returning an Activity from your methods won't confuse

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was all messed up because of the Contact_ID i was using.
Raw_Contact ID resolved my problem. Thank you